# python error Talentbuddy:EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, eoferror

I wrote some python code on ***Talentbuddy's*** code editor which lead to an EOFError: EOF when reading a line, but I ran the same code on python IDLE and everything is ok.
The code is meant to simply sum the number is given by ***Talenbuddy***, but I don't know how to get the number.

```
def get_sum(a,b):
    c=a+b
    return c
a=raw_input()
b=raw_input()
print get_sum(a,b)
```

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "eval_get_sum.py", line 3, in 
>       from user_file import get_sum
>        File "/eval/user_file.py", line 4, in 
>       a=raw_input()
>       EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is "Simple Sum", you aren't supposed to be taking any `raw_input`. When you click "Check Solution", the system will *call* your function, providing appropriate arguments `a` and `b`; you don't have to call it yourself. Remove the last three lines and test again.